# How to decrease 83V 17Ah DC battery to 72V?

Tags: voltage, power, resistors, voltage-regulator

I purchased a 72 V 20 Ah battery pack for my electric bike. When the battery came, I tested the voltage and amperage and found that the battery came to be ~83 V and ~18 Ah.

My bike's controller can't function properly with this overvoltage, so I need a way to decrease the voltage to the intended 72 V, while trying to keep the Ah as high as possible.

Is there any way to achieve this? Maybe by the use of resistors? I really don't know where to start.

Comment: Are you sure your bike can't handle that voltage?  What battery did the bike manufacturer recommend?  It's not unusual for a new unloaded battery to show a voltage above its nominal rating.

Comment: That may be OK.  A fully charged "72 volt" lead-acid type battery would be about 81 volts.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned it the comments, the voltage across a Li-Ion based battery varies a lot between discharged and charged state. For laptop batteries (also Li-Ion based) most manufacturers use 3.6 V per cell as the nominal voltage but this will increase to 4.2 V per cell when fully charged.

So 72 V / 3.6 V = 20 cells

fully charged that could be upto:

20 x 4.2 V = 84 V

So 83 V for fully charged looks perfectly normal to me :-)

If you still have doubts, then fully charge the original battery and measure its voltage, I bet that it will also reach at least 83 V !

Answer (score 0):

High voltage Boost converters / regulators. They are better then linear ones with less losses albeit with a bit more complicated wireing and abit more parts.

Something like http://www.linear.com/product/LTC3703 or similar? There is a ton of boost converters out there.

Resistors wont help you much as load is variable so a voltage divider will vary and such. its only good for something with a static load connected.

With that said if you bought it at 72 volts and it states 72 volts but reads higher that voltage might just be on unloaded measurement. hook up something to it that draws a relatively small ammount of current out and remeasure the voltage to see if it stabilises at 72.

Comment: Not sure you mean boost here - you're trying to go from 83V down to 72V - you'll be wanting a Buck converter for that. The LTC3703 would potentially work, however.